# Java Cipher update()/doFinal() with Streams aligned to block size

Tags: java, encryption, stream

Imagine we have InputStream to read data, OutputStream to write data and Cipher.
We do encrypt data this way:

```
int bs = 4096;
Cipher cipher = ...;
InputStream input = ...;
OutputStream output = ...;
int count = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bs];
while (true)
{
  count = input.read(buffer, 0, bs);

  if (count < bs)
    break;

  byte[] encrypted = cipher.update(buffer, 0, count);
  output.write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.length);
}

if (count > 0)
{
  byte[] final = cipher.doFinal(buffer, 0, count);
  output.write(final, 0, final.length);
}
```

But what if data is exactly 4096 bytes or a multiple? This way we'll call update but next iteration we get count = -1 from input as nothing left, so we skip doFinal() part. How to prevent skipping doFinal()? Or can we just call doFinal(buffer, 0, 0) with 0 length?

Comment: I think the better solution will be iterate over buffer, instead while(true).
Or separate into a function or method, its gonna fix your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An input buffer doesn't necessarily reach the end of the stream if it returns less data than the buffer size, so the whole idea of using that as final block is wrong (it generally works for files, but it may not work with other streams, and **especially** `CipherInputStream`.

What you need to do is to write data until the `read` method returns `-1`:

```
void copy(InputStream source, OutputStream target) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    while ((length = source.read(buf)) != -1) {
        target.write(buf, 0, length);
    }
}
```

Here you use this fact about [`InputStream#read(byte[] b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)):

> If the length of `b` is zero, then no bytes are read and `0` is returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file, **the value `-1` is returned**; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into `b`.

Furthermore, you can simply use `CipherOutputStream` to wrap the given `OutputStream`. For Java 9 onwards, you can also use [`InputStream#transferTo(OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-) to make life simpler, no need to mess with buffered reads / writes.

Finally, using try-with-resources is highly recommended. Don't forget to close those streams, *especially* `CipherOutputStream` as otherwise the final part of the ciphertext might not be written to your output stream.

---

No doubt calling `doFinal` without data also works. `doFinal` without data just transforms any bytes left in the internal buffer of the implementation of the cipher.